# HAProxy crashes on all requests in 1.5-dev12

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I'm having an issue where HAProxy is crashing with no explanation when I switch from 1.4.12 to 1.5-dev12. The reason I'm switching is for the SSL offloading.

My config file doesn't have any errors, it's quite simple and it works well with 1.4 - but for some reason when I run it with 1.5-dev12 I see the logs noting that the two backends I have have been set up, and then when I hit one of the frontends, I get an HTTP 400 in the browser and suddenly HAProxy isn't running anymore when I check.

I understand that a common workaround to the lack of SSL support for HAProxy is to use Stud, and I may go with that since I am in need of an SSL solution for my service, but before I dele into that world I thought I might see if anybody has experienced the same problems and might know how to fix it.

The server is Ubuntu 10.04 and I followed the make instructions on the Exceliance blog [here](http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/09/04/howto-ssl-native-in-haproxy/).

EDIT: On the advice of Kyle Brandt, I did a bit more investigation. I attached gdb to the haproxy process and when the crash occurred this is what I got:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804e5c2 in dequeue_all_listeners (list=0x9e1a418) at src/protocols.c:184
184     list_for_each_entry_safe(listener, l_back, list, wait_queue) {
```

P.S. HAProxy is awesome, so thank you Exceliance for providing us with something so useful :)

Comment: The haproxy author watch this tag, so will be probably see this. In the meantime, he has instructions for getting a core dump in this mailing list message: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/7992

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I've put in the info. Again, if anybody knows the cause and if there's a workaround for the time being, I'd love to know please :)

Answer (score 1):

sorry I did not see your post.

We fixed a segfault this week related to the change in connection management. However it
was not as easy to get as yours and given your gdb output I'm not sure it's the same one.
Could you please try with the latest snapshot from this night and see if you can reproduce
it ? If so I'm interested in getting the core and the config file off-list.

Thanks to you and Kyle for his endless help on the subject :-)